# Checking battery state errors

Tags: boot, battery

First of all, I'm going to need VERY specific answers for I switched to Linux from Windows a week ago and don't know much. Basically when Ubuntu starts it hangs on "Checking battery state". I'm on a desktop, not a laptop. If I do Ctrl+Alt+F5 and "sudo reboot" about 2 or 3 times it will eventually boot into Ubuntu, but this is quite frustrating. Any detailed help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? (ex. 11.04, 11.10?) Also how long were you waiting?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Mm... I have faced the same problem recently, but don't remember what i did to it to work ;-( If you have installed Ubuntu inside windows, try to run **check disk** the partition of the Wubi installation (Ubuntu installation) and boot into Ubuntu again, what have you done before this problem, I think you have done something wrong with the **GDM** (Gnome display manager) is it?

Comment: No Wubi. I regret installing Ubuntu. I'm just not smart enough to get it, I've always considered myself good with computers but...VirtualMachines are nice but they can't run my games =(

Comment: You could try without removing windows,Installing inside windows means install using wubi, not VM. maybe it's your X server. because after battery staes it loads the x server configs, you probably have messed around, Use the live cd and copy data you sored in ubuntu partition(Your stuff like music) and reinstall ubuntu.